# How to return(pass) all hosts not in acl - Varnish

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

So here is what I am trying to accomplish. Im trying to get varnish working on a shared environment and I would like to set it up to where only domains within a vcl include get cached and the rest are simply passed. Here is what I am looking at:

```
include "/etc/varnish/whitelist.vcl";
if (req.http.host !~ vhosts) {
   return(pass);
}


acl vhosts {
"domain.net";
"www.domain.net";
"...";
}
```

...

Now varnish tells me that this isnt possible:

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected CSTR got 'vhosts'
(program line 940), at
('input' Line 11 Pos 30)
if (req.http.host !~ vhosts) {
-----------------------------######---

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1

VCL compilation failed
```

Now I know I can just do the following:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "domain1.com" || 
        req.http.host == "domain2.com") {
        return(pass);
    }
}
```

But I really like the clean look of the first. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't use ACL for HTTP Host header. It's for matching client address only

Answer (score 0):

ghloogh is kindof right, except you can use std.ip() function to convert IP addresses to correct format for matching against acls. Still doesn't work with hostnames though.

But I suggest you use regular expressions instead of individual string matches, like so:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host ~ "^(domain1.com|domain2.com)$") {
        return(pass);
    }
}
```